# Namespace django app names

Tags: python, django

I have tried searching around for this, but searches including "django", "app", and "namespace" all bring up topics mostly relating to URLConf, not what I want to know.

In Django settings, apps included in a project are listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Most community-released apps are not "namespaced" in that the app name consists of only letters, numbers, and underscores. There are official apps like "django.contrib.sites" that are "namespaced" with dot-syntax. What I cannot seem to find is: how do I do this? For example, if I want to create an app like "mycompany.app". The `startapp` command of manage.py does not allow naming like this if I try `./manage.py "mycompany.app"`, complaining of invalid characters.

So what Python and/or Django magic am I missing to create and use apps in this way? Or is there some reason why doing this is discouraged, and I should only make apps like "mycompany_app"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a python package `mycompany` (i.e. folder with **init**.py file inside), inside create package `app`.

There is also namespace term in django urls, can be noticed in calls like `reverse('namespace:view-name')`, here is the doc for these: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces